# How to re-add the Facebook tile?

Tags: tiles

The Facebook tile was accidentally deleted from the Start screen. Is there a way to get it back? I succeeded in getting it back by pressing the Facebook button on the Apps list, but the result isn't quite the same as in the original—the restored Facebook tile on the start screen is now just the *F* on a blue background, while in the original tile all the images inside ( i.e the pics of my contacts)  were "moving". Do I have to reset the phone? In that case, I think I would lose all data (phone numbers, messages), wouldn't I?

Comment: And what is FB?

Comment: @paranoid FB -> Facebook. And `Ross`, The blue app with F is the [Facebook app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e). `row1` just posted an answer about the people-hub. It has many photos changing on it and in the ads is common to see one litle facebook icon too.

Comment: @VitorCanova it's not the people hub i'm talking about, it was a facebook only tile, i'm 100% sure, and it worked like a people hub. i saw a person deleting it.

Comment: Try looking in your Facebook app settings, maybe there is a special live tile that can be configured there? Or maybe a way to configure the live tiles so that it displays photos etc.?

Comment: The live tiles don't update right away. Initially it'll just be a "boring" icon, but after some time it'll start behaving the way it used to. I haven't yet figured out what this time is, so it's quite possible that it's somewhat random.

Comment: @RobinAshe I haven't seen this, are you able to take a photo and post it as an answer?

Comment: Nothing really to take a photo of, when it doesn't update it's just the front side of the tile and doesn't flip.

Answer (score 8):

Are you referring to the *people* live title?

[image: People live tile]

If so then:

1. On Start, flick left to the App list.
2. Navigate down to *People*.
3. Tap and hold the *People* app, then tap *Pin to Start*.

You don't need to reset your phone.

Comment: No, I meant the FB "live title" or button

Comment: Did the Facebook tile come installed with the phone or did you manually add it and forget how you did it? As far as I know the people tile is the only title with moving social pictures that matches your description and the only one that comes installed on the phone.

Comment: it came installed on the phone.

Comment: The People Hub automatically remembers the way you left it last, so you could be thinking it was a different app then. To demonstrate, go into your people hub and slide over to the panorama item that has the moving images of your contacts. Then tap the start button to exit the app. Now when ever you enter the app, you will land on the same place you exited. It can appear to be a different app if you left it from a different place before. Furthermore, you can filter the "what's new" list to show just your facebook friends by tapping the account under "what's New"

Comment: @LanceMcCarthy it's not the people hub i'm talking about, it was a facebook only tile, i'm 100% sure, and it worked like a people hub. i saw a person deleting it.

Comment: @Ross In people hub there is a section called "what's new". Below this word has a filter with accent color where you can choose only Facebook instead of all. Is it?

Comment: The official Facebook app does not have a live tile with moving pictures or people hub-like behavior. It sounds like you had the People hub set to show Facebook posts only and kept it set to What's New.